# Merging tables and modifying string records in SQL (Microsoft access)

Tags: sql, string, ms-access-2007

Beginner SQL question. Suppose I have two tables

table1

```
ID name1 name2 name3
-- ----- ----- -----
1  blah1  high south
2  blah2  low  north  
3  blah3  high north
4  blah4  low  south
```

table2

```
ID head1 head2
-- ----- ----------
1  blah5  super high south
2  blah6  medium high northern
3  blah7  kind of low north
4  blah8  kind of low south
```

Now I want to add the records of `table2` to `table1`. But the data for columns `name2` and `name3` are combined in strings in `head2` of `table1`.  So I want to extract these fields from `head2' and put them in`table1' so that it looks like this

table1

```
ID name1 name2 name3  
-- ----- ----- -----
1  blah1  high south
2  blah2  low  north 
3  blah3  high north 
4  blah4  low  south
5  blah5  high south
6  blah6  high north
7  blah7  low  north 
8  blah8  low  south
```

Now I have in mind some kind of `IF` statement (but have no idea how to implement this in SQL)

```
for each record in table2 do
    table1.name1.insert(head1)
    if table2.head2 == "super high south" then
        table1.name2.insert(high)
        table1.name3.insert(south)
    if table2.head2 == "medium high northern" then
        table1.name2.insert(high)
        table1.name3.insert(north)  

    etc....
```

In my actual application there is a limited number of unique string types in `head2` so an if statement for each one is feasible

How would you write an SQL query (for Microsoft Access) to do this?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Where do the `name2` and `name3` values come for `blah5`, `blah6`, etcetera?

Comment: Probably easiest is to create a keyword table for high, low etc and a query that evaluates the data from table 2 ( head2 like keyword ). This will get complicated if you have two keywords eg super high.

Answer (score 0):

With a limited number of [head2] values you could code your "if statement" logic using the `Switch()` function like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (name1, name2, name3)
SELECT
    head1 AS name1,
    Switch(
        head2="super high south", "high",
        head2="medium high northern", "high",
        head2="kind of low north", "low",
        head2="kind of low south", "low")
        AS name2,
    Switch(
        head2="super high south", "south",
        head2="medium high northern", "north",
        head2="kind of low north", "north",
        head2="kind of low south", "south")
        AS name3
FROM table2
```